# Is there an easy way to Mass Update Opportunity Close Dates?

Tags: opportunity

We have a lot of data that was added to Salesforce that has not been updated in 2 years. I have been tasked with organizing and validating the information in Salesforce. I need to mass update opportunities with realistic close dates. Tons of data. Is there an easy way to Mass Update Opportunity Close Dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, The steps are simple and you have a few tools to choose from.

1. Export opportunities
2. Manually specify your Close Date(s) for each opportunity.
3. Re-import opportunities with updated Closed Date(s)

**Exporting**

You can use the Salesforce Data Loader to export your opportunities into a spreadsheet, or create a Salesforce report of opportunities which you can also export as a spreadsheet.

In either case, make sure your resulting spreadsheet includes the Opportunity ID column. You'll need it when you re-import back your updates.

**Importing**

Once again, you can use the Salesforce Data Loader with this, or you can use Salesforce's native Data Import Wizard in **Setup | Import | Data Import Wizard.**

In either case, just follow through the wizard to import your updated opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it correctly what I would do is do a report in opportunity with the Opportunity ID, Opportunity names, and close dates.  Once you have that data I would use DataLoader to update the necessary records.

How much data do you have?  You can also use DataLoader to export the records you need.